# What is the main difference between AsyncTask() and Handler()?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am a beginner in android app developing.

I have to use ping test in my app for checking available internet connection as I have found this method very useful, but I read at many places that I should use AsyncTask() method or Handler() method as ping test on UI thread may freeze my app.

But I am not getting the difference between those two to decide which one I should use. I found that in AsyncTask, I have methods like doInBackground() and onPostExecute which helps in interaction with UI thread and processes run in another thread.

But I am not getting such methods in Handler() method.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable =new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
     handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
 }
};
handler.post(runnable);
```

1. I am not getting which method in Handler() is running in background and which method are helpful for making the app run in background like I found in AsyncTask().
2. I am not understanding the difference between those two.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and Main Difference between them is

An AsyncTask is used to do some background Task and publish the result to the UI thread with/without progress update.

If you're not concerned with UI, then a Handler/Thread are more appropriate.